# Using ActiveRecord with column names with spaces in them

Tags: ruby, sql-server, activerecord, jruby, factory-bot

I work on a team that is using ActiveRecord to access the schema on a MSSQL server. Modifying the schema is not an option and the column names have spaces in them, a la `SPACEY COLUMN`.

When writing the ActiveRecord class to access a table with spaces in it, what is good practice?

We also need this to work with factory girl...

Comment: I don't know ActiveRecord from a hole in the ground, but in general, if spaces in column or table names are giving you issues, you can use double quotes: `"SPACEY COLUMN"` or square brackets: `[SPACEY COLUMN]`.

Answer (score 1):

AR-JDBC (as well as the AR-SQLServer-Adapter) will/should handle this just fine since it auto-magically quotes column name identifiers using "[ COlumn NAME ]" ... I personally would hide this from bubbling up as much as possible e.g. using aliases :

```
class MySpacey < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'SPACEY TABLE'
  set_primary_key 'MY ID'
  alias_attribute :id, :'MY ID'
end
```

Comment: what is that thing that looks like a mix between a symbol and a string (`:'MY ID'`)?

Comment: no unless of course `alias_attribute` complains that it needs a symbol ... I do not think it's relevant here

Comment: I tried `:'MY ID'.class` and it output `Symbol`. I learned something new. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider `User` is the Model and `User Name` is the column you need to access.

```
User.where('User Name' => 'Bob')
```

You can add multiple conditions also,

```
User.where('User Name' => 'Bob', 'Email Address' => 'sample@sample.com')
```

You can also try,

```
User.where('[User name] = ? AND [Email Address] = ?', 'Bob', 'sample@sample.com')
```

And if your table itself has space in it. Try,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "user table"
end
```