# How to specify an ActiveRecord attribute for a timestamp when the column name has spaces?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a column in my postgres database like this:

```
"Last Execution Timestamp" timestamp without time zone,
```

Literally a column name in quotes with spaces, for timestamp.

How would I set and get such an attribute in ActiveRecord? I've tried the following in factory_girl:

```
object["Last Execution Timestamp"]  = rand(0..60).days.ago
```

which causes the following exception:

```
gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@ddr-rails4/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/time_zone_conversion.rb:36: 
dynamic constant assignment
      def Last Execution Timestamp=(time)

/ruby-2.0.0-p0@ddr-rails4/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/time_zone_conversion.rb:38: 
syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting ')'
... read_attribute(:Last Execution Timestamp)
```

Same exception when I try to create an alias_attribute..
The same code works if the column type is a "date", but this needs to be a timestamp. Any suggestions?

Comment: Load up your rails console. Check the result of Object.new.methods and see what it's named as.

Comment: rails console will not load, hits this error before anything loads

Comment: You need to comment out the offending code before you do any tests.

Comment: Have you tried escaping, like object["Last\ Execution\ Timestamp"] ?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate question. Please see: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22206018/using-activerecord-with-column-names-with-spaces-in-them"